# How to properly implement a custom control that handles mnemonics?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, custom-controls

I am implementing a custom control in WinForms. This control needs to respond to a mnemonic character, and the mnemonic needs to focus the next control in the tab order - like a Label control does.

The `ProcessMnemonic` method is clearly the one to override. However, looking at how the Label control does it, for reference, shows that it relies heavily on WinForms internals:

- To check whether it's OK to respond to the mnemonic, the Label uses an internal CanProcessMnemonic method.
- The method requests a UIPermission, and then uses a bunch of internal classes and calls to verify that focus may be changed.
- Focus is changed with the use of an internal "ParentInternal" field.

I didn't expect that responding to a mnemonic could be so involved. It seems to work if I omit all those internal calls and just use the non-internal Parent, but it makes me wonder: surely that code is not there for nothing, so my naive implementation must be lacking something?

Here's the Label's real code, tweaked slightly by me for readability:

```
[UIPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Window=UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)]
protected internal override bool ProcessMnemonic(char charCode)
{
    if ((!UseMnemonic || !IsMnemonic(charCode, Text)) || !CanProcessMnemonic() /*internal*/)
        return false;

    if (ParentInternal != null) /* internal */
    {
        IntSecurity.ModifyFocus.Assert(); /* internal */
        try
        {
            if (ParentInternal.SelectNextControl(this, true, false, true, false) && !ParentInternal.ContainsFocus)
                ParentInternal.Focus();
        }
        finally
        {
            CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's my "naive" rewrite of it:

```
protected override bool ProcessMnemonic(char charCode)
{
    if ((!UseMnemonic || !IsMnemonic(charCode, Text)) || !Enabled || !Visible)
        return false;

    if (Parent != null)
        if (Parent.SelectNextControl(this, true, false, true, false) && !Parent.ContainsFocus)
            Parent.Focus();

    return true;
}
```

One obvious difference is that `CanProcessMnemonic` recursively checks the parent, which my code doesn't because this method is, inexplicably, internal...

Comment: I think you're over thinking this one a little bit. Besides you don't ask a specific question here that could merit a solid response. I'm not sure about the difference between ParentInternal and Parent, but the other stuff has to do with UI security. This ensures that other code that does not have permission to access your UI can't interact with your mneumonic handling. I'm not an expert in this either, and hence do not offer an answer. But you can read more on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.uipermissionwindow.aspx

Comment: @BenSwayne The specific question is in the title. I sometimes repeat it at the end, but this time I didn't. What makes you think I'm over-thinking? If this is trivial then could you show how exactly I should do it, and why I can ignore the complexities?

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override bool ProcessMnemonic(char charCode)
    {
        if (IsMnemonic(charCode, LabelButton.Text) == true)
        {
            Focus(); // TODO

            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessMnemonic(charCode);
    }
```

Comment: Please add a bit of a preface and some context to your answer. Thanks!